# Создание адресной книги на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здорова всем В книге 'A byte of Python' была в конце задача: 
Создайте собственную программу «Адресная книга», работающую из командной строки и позволяющую просматривать,добавлять,изменять,удалять или искать контактные данные ваших знакомых. Кроме того,этаинформациятакжедолжнасохранятьсянадиске для последующего доступа. Вопрос: при изменении контакта - не изменяется, при добавлении - добавляется и сразу выходит из программы, ведь я не хочу чтобы программа выходила, но при следующем запуске как был создан контакт так остался, что же я не так делаю? Подскажите, или хоть намекните как нужно пожалуйста.

```
import pickle


class Address:
    # Имя файла в котором будет сохранён объект.
    library = 'Book.data'
    ab = {'Воронин': 'voron@mail.ru'}

    # Запись в файл.
    f = open(library, 'wb')
    pickle.dump(ab, f)  # Помещаем объект в файл.
    f.close()

    del ab  # Удаляем переменную ab.

    # Считываем из хранилища.
    f = open(library, 'rb')
    stored = pickle.load(f)  # Загружаем объект из файла.
    print(stored)

    def __init__(self, name, address, new_name, new_address):
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.new_name = new_name
        self.new_address = new_address

    def __add__(self):
        self.name = input('Введите имя: ')
        self.address = input('Введите адрес: ')
        Address.stored[self.name] = self.address
        print('Адрес добавлен')
        print('В адерсной книге {0 
               контактов.'.format(len(Address.stored)))

    def change(self):
        self.name = input('Введите имя которое нужно изменить: ')
        if input(self.name) in Address.stored:
            del Address.stored[self.name]  # Удаляю введённый выше 
                                             контакт.
            self.new_name = input('Введите новое имя: ')  # Ввожу новый 
                                                          контакт.
            Address.stored[self.new_name] = self.address  # Добавляю в 
                                                          книгу.
        self.address = input('Введите адрес который нужно изменит: ')
        if input(self.address) in Address.stored:
            del Address.stored[self.address]  # Удаляю старый адрес.
            self.new_address = input('Введите новый адрес: ')  # Ввожу 
                                            новый адрес.
            Address.stored[self.name] = self.new_address  # Добавляю в 
                                                         книгу.

    def __delete__(self):
        self.name = input('Введите имя которе нужно удалить: ')
        del Address.stored[self.name]

    def find(self):
        self.name = input('Введите имя для поиска контакта: ')
        print('Адрес:', Address.stored[self.name])


A = Address(name=None, address=None, new_name=None, new_address=None)
num = int(input('Какое действие необходимо сделать: 1-Добавить; 2- 
                            Изменить; 3-Удалить; 4-Найти: '))
if num == 1:
    A.__add__()
if num == 2:
    A.change()
if num == 3:
    A.__delete__()
if num == 4:
    A.find()

print(Address.stored)
```

Вот пример вывода при изменении:

```
{'Воронин': 'voron@mail.ru'}
Какое действие необходимо сделать: 1-Добавить; 2-Изменить; 3-Удалить; 4- 
Найти: 2
Введите имя которое нужно изменить: Воронин
ВоронинВоронин
Введите новое имя: Андрей
Введите адрес который нужно изменит: voron@mail.ru
voron@mail.ruvoron@mail.ru
{'Андрей': None}
```

Comment: А Вы читали книгу? Или сразу задачу в конце открыли?

Comment: Ну конечно читал. Или стоит ещё раз прочитать книгу?

Comment: Думаю, стоило бы. Мои придирки: переопределение магических методов, неуместные переменные класса, переприсваивание полей экземпляра класса, не закрыли файл после работы с ним, никак не обрабатывается ввод пользователя.

Comment: На счёт закрытия файла - это я помнил, но упустил. Объясни пожалуйста что значит переопределение магических методов,нужно было использовать стандартные методы? На счёт обработки ввода - у меня мыслей пока нет, как правильно их обработать. И по поводу переписывания переменных экземпляра класса поясните пожалуйста.

Comment: У меня почему-то в выводе при изменении когда пишу имя - оно дублируется, и необходимо снова писать его же. Вот тоже не понимаю почему, но это я думаю надо как Вы сказали обработать ввод.

Comment: Магические методы - обособлены `__` с двух сторон, почитайте про них. Обработка ввода - можно банально обратиться к имени, которого нет и сработает исключение. Переприсваивание полей класса - у Вас переменные `self.***` нужны только для пользовательского ввода? Так не делается. Переменные класса - представьте, что у Вас несколько экземпляров телефонных справочников, но во всех них одно и то же. Это, по-вашему, нормально?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что `input` это функция? Она точно так же вызывается и возвращает значение, как и любая другая функция. Какой смысл в строке `if input(self.address) in Address.stored`?

Comment: Строкой if input(self.address) in Address.stored я хотел сказать:  то что ведь мы хотим изменить определённое имя, мы его вводим и тем временем нам же нужно написать имя на которое нужно изменить, вот и self.name где мы вводим имя которое мы хотим поменять, а ниже уже записываем на какое имя меняем, и это имя добавляем в книгу.

Comment: А хотя зачем нам его добавлять, оно же просто изменяется.

Comment: Ладно. Если что я к Вам ещё раз обращусь за помощью. Хорошо?